# Access denied to file in my Google App Engine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase

I'm developing an application backend using Google App Engine in Android Studio. I want to use Firebase so part of it's SDK initialization is read a Service account Credentials JSON file. I added the file to my "src" directory and try to read it like in the Firebase's doc:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("/src/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();
```

But it always throw exception that access to the file is denied:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: 
    access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/src/serviceAccountCredentials.json" "read")
```

How can I change the read permission to this file?
Thanks :)

Comment: you're putting it into classpath, so you should read it as a resource (even outside of App Engine)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Can you give me example how to get the FileInputStream from this file as resource? Or how to add it not as classpath? thanks

Comment: not a _file_ input stream, just input stream. i'll give an answer

Comment: also, make sure you really need to setup ServiceAccount on App Engine. I have no experience with Firebase, but every other Google Cloud service have simplified method to setup access from App Engine, w/o providing credentials

Answer (score 1):

Your is located in the source dir, so after compilation it should be at root of classpatch. But make sure it's there, it depend on build tools actually, some of them can ignore non source file in `src` dir, because such files should be in `resources` dir. If that your case, the move file to resources dir.

Then, to read this file, you have to use it as a resource:

```
InputStream cred = this.getClass()
          .getResourceAsStream("/serviceAccountCredentials.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
         .setServiceAccount(cred)
         .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com/")
         .build();
```

Comment: That's not working... the getResourcesAsStream returns null... I also tried to move the json into resources directory instead the src as you said, still not working :/ Any other possible way?

Comment: hm, can you try with slash? ie `"/serviceAccountCredentials.json"`? and make sure it's in output classes dir

Comment: Ok the problem acctually was the json location... I placed it in the root of the project instead inside the main directory. Now it works, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file in your appengine-web.xml file under the  tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myApplicationId</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <resource-files>
        <include path="secret.json" />
    </resource-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This way your app engine server will come to know that you are using this static resource which is read only.